# Automapper: List to members

Tags: c#, automapper

I'd like to map an arbitrary list of abstract types to an arbitrary set of properties, that share the same base type.
Here is some UnitTest code, which currently fails and which I want to success. Could you help me, get a generic solution?

Here are the classes:

```
 public class Source
{
    public string Name { get; set; } = "SomeName";
    public Dictionary<string, ValueType> SourceList { get; set; } = new Dictionary<string, ValueType>();
}
public interface IDestination
{
    string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Destination : IDestination     //And many other classes like this, with other properties inherited from ValueType
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public double DoubleValue { get; set; }
    public int IntValue { get; set; }

    public string SomeOtherProperty { get; set; }
}
```

And here is the unit test, I'd like to succeed:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        var source = new Source();
        source.SourceList.Add("IntValue", (int) 3);
        source.SourceList.Add("DoubleValue", (double) 3.14);

        Mapper.Initialize(config =>
        {
            //Put in some magic code here!!!
        });

        var destinationAbstract = Mapper.Map<Source, IDestination>(source);     //the type of destination is known only at runtime. Therefore Mapping to Interface

        var destination = (Destination) destinationAbstract;
        Assert.AreEqual(source.Name, destination.Name);
        Assert.AreEqual((int)source.SourceList["IntValue"], destination.IntValue);
        Assert.AreEqual((double)source.SourceList["DoubleValue"], destination.DoubleValue);
    }
```

Please be aware, that

- the number of classes, that inherit from IDestination is only known at runtime
- the content of the SourceList may be different for each Source-instance and therefore the properties of the destination class could also change for each class definition

I hope you can help me, because I wasn't able to determine a generic solution with the help of the documentation.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can map from `Dictionary<string, object>`(property names to property values) to some class by default, without any extra configuration. The [docs](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Dynamic-and-ExpandoObject-Mapping) and the [tests](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/blob/859612d672a45c62f3cce5c8b236be796497c916/src/UnitTests/Mappers/StringDictionaryMapperTests.cs).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. As far as I understand, this mapping only works for source type Dictionary<string,object> and no other Dictionary type. If I am right, how would this help with my Dictionary<string,ValueType>? (note: ValueType is just an example for any self-defined base type)

Comment: I tried using a mapping for Dictionary<string, object>, but there are two problems: 1.) My source type is Dictionary<string, ValueType> and I don't want to cast to object. And 2.) My destination type is holds also other members, which are not read from a source dictionary.

Comment: Why not? And about your second point, all entries in the source dictionary that have matching destination properties will be mapped, so I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: About the second point: If you map a dictionary to an object with members, it only works correctly, if all members do exist in the dictionary. If you have any general member (like "Name" in my example), the mapping to this member won't work. Therefore I had to do the trick with two calls to Mapper.Map: one for general members and one for members which could be mapped from the dictionary.

Comment: Yes, that's true, static and dynamic mapping don't mix. You can use AfterMap for example, so you'll have only one map call. The mapper is general, so it has to be object based. How else could it possibly work? :)

Answer (score 0):

After considering Lucians hint and after trying different things with Automapper, I finally found a solution for my initial unit-test:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        var source = new Source();
        source.SourceList.Add("IntValue", (int) 3);
        source.SourceList.Add("DoubleValue", (double) 3.14);

        Mapper.Initialize(config =>
        {
            //"Magic code"
            config.CreateMap<Source, IDestination>();
            config.CreateMap(typeof(Source), typeof(Destination)).IncludeBase(typeof(Source), typeof(IDestination));
        });

        //standard map-call
        var destination = Mapper.Map<Destination>(source);
        //Additional "Trick":
        Dictionary<string, object> mappingDict =
            source.SourceList.ToDictionary(pair => pair.Key, pair => (object) pair.Value);
        Mapper.Map(mappingDict, destination, typeof(Dictionary<string, object>), typeof(Destination));

        Assert.AreEqual(source.Name, destination.Name);
        Assert.AreEqual(source.SourceList["IntValue"], destination.IntValue);
        Assert.AreEqual(source.SourceList["DoubleValue"], destination.DoubleValue);
    }
```

The "trick" is to cast my `Dictionary<string, ValueType>` to `Dictionary<string,object>` and to map this dictionary-member to the destination object in addition(!) to the standard map-call. 
This works, but has some drawbacks:

1. Mapping validation is not possible (Validation says: either source member "SourceList" is not mapped or the destination members "DoubleValue" or "IntValue" are not mapped)
2. Casting the dictionary is kind of ugly (and seems unnecessary to me...)
3. I need 2 calls to Mapper.Map instead of only one.

It seems to me, that there is no other way to solve my initial problem. But I am open for any suggestions or improvements to my solution.
The initial problem could be solved also easily through using reflections, so all information for a proper mapping setup should be existent, but I was not able to find this proper mapping setup.

Comment: About validation, you can get it by defining a source interface that only has the static members.