# .NET - Convert/map list into object and vis versa

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, list, serialization, automapper

I have the following list which contains field names and values.

```
public class FormField 
{
    public string FieldName { get; set;}
    public string FieldValue { get; set;}
}

var formData = new List<FormField>();
formData.Add(new FormField { FieldName = "Date", FieldValue = "2017-09-14" });
formData.Add(new FormField { FieldName = "Name", FieldValue = "Job blogs" });
formData.Add(new FormField { FieldName = "IsEnabled", FieldValue = "true" });
```

How can I convert or map the list into the following class? Note FieldNames map to the properties of the class.

```
public class MyViewModel 
{
    [Required]
    public DateTime Date { get; set; } = DateTime.now;

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public boolean IsEnabled { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Titles 
    {
        get
        {
            var options = new List<SelectListItem>
            {
                new SelectListItem(){ Value = "Mr", Text = "Mr" },
                new SelectListItem(){ Value = "Mrs", Text = "Mrs" }                    
            };

            return options;
        }
    } 
}
```

Any help appreciated. Do I need to serialize the list somehow? Can automapper do this?

*** UPDATE ***

I tried the following but it doesnt work despite the automapper docs stating that you can go directly from dictionary to object:

```
public class MappingProfile : Profile
{
    public MappingProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<Dictionary<string, object>, MyViewModel>();
    }
}

var viewModel = Mapper.Map<MyViewModel>(formData.ToDictionary(x => x.FieldName, x => (object) x.FieldValue))
```

Note: for the record I'm using automapper v 5.0.2

I also need to go back from object to dictionary but be able to exclude properties such as `public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Titles {get;}`

Comment: Yes Automapper can do this, or you can manually map the values in MyViewModel's constructor by passing the object of FormField as parameter if you want to avoid the overhead of Automapper.

Comment: @TechGirl any code to assist ? mapping in constructor would not be ideal.

Comment: @TechGirl, Really? I very much doubt that.

Comment: You would need to loop through the collection, get the property name and set the associated property value using conditional statements ( `if (FieldName == "Date") { model.Date = ...`, or use reflection to match up the property names (using `PropertyInfo`)

Comment: I was thinking the same as @StephenMuecke but you can replace the if statements for a "switch" of course you can do this in a different function and call it when you need it

Comment: @Stephen Muecke I've over 50 fields which would end up as really dirty code to loop using conditonal statements. How would I do it using refelction?

Comment: @adam78 if you want a dynamic object, use dynamic types like ExpandoObject and the `dynamic` keyword. Internally, [ExpandoObject](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/csharpfaq/2009/09/30/dynamic-in-c-4-0-introducing-the-expandoobject/) holds a dictionary of member names and their values. Your code is trying to recreate ExpandoObject. You wouldn't need to map anything with Expando. In fact, that's how ViewBag works

Comment: @adam78 a more advanced scenario is to derive from [DynamicObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.dynamicobject(v=vs.110).aspx) . This allows you to control how fields are stored, how they are added, removed etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use reflection to get and set the matching properties in the model

```
var formData = new List<FormField>();
formData.Add(new FormField { FieldName = "Date", FieldValue = "2017-09-14" });
formData.Add(new FormField { FieldName = "Name", FieldValue = "Job blogs" });
formData.Add(new FormField { FieldName = "IsEnabled", FieldValue = "true" });

// Initialize a new instance of the model
MyViewmodel model = new MyViewmodel();
// Get its property info
PropertyInfo[] properties = model.GetType().GetProperties();
// Loop through your form field data
foreach(var field in formData)
{
    // Get the matching property name
    PropertyInfo pi = properties.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == field.FieldName);
    if (pi == null)
    {
        continue;
    }
    // Convert the value to match the property type
    object value = Convert.ChangeType(field.FieldValue, pi.PropertyType);
    // Set the value of the property
    pi.SetValue(model, value);
}
```

Comment: what about using an intermediate serialization see following. In this instace I would convert the list into a dictionary - (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7310533/dictionary-string-string-map-to-an-object-using-automapper)

Comment: Well as Darin said - _You could cheat_, and it would involve extra overhead code and overhead

Comment: Actually the extra overhead would only apply if using AutoMapper, which is probably not necessary.

Comment: What about the boolean properties in the view model. In my list they are strings so will they get mapped to their boolean equivalent if I was to simply cheat using Darins method?

Comment: Not sure - only tested my answer (using `Convert.ChangeType(..)` will do it correctly)

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are trying to create an object that contains a dynamic number of fields, like ViewBag. You don't need mapping for this. That's already provided by .NET, through the ExpandoObject, DynamicObject classes and `dynamic` keyword.

Instead of building a list of fields and values, create an ExpandoObject and add fields to it, just as you would with ViewBag :

```
dynamic formData=new ExpandoObject();
formData.Name = "Job blogs";
formData.Date = DateTime.Today;
formData.IsEnabled = true;
formData.Titles = new []{ 
                           new SelectedListeItem{Text="Mr",Value="Mr"},
                           new SelectedListeItem{Text="Mrs",Value="Mrs"}
                        };
```

You can use that object as your ViewModel, just like ViewBag.

```
// Controller 

public ActionResult Index(..)
{
    ....
    View(formData);
}


//View 
@model dynamic 

<h1>@Model.Name</h1>
```

**UPDATE - Expando from field list**

[ExpandoObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject(v=vs.110).aspx) implements `IDictionary<string, object>` explicitly, which means that one can properties without knowing their number or names at runtime, eg:

```
var fields = new (string name,object value) [] 
             {
                        ("Name","Job blogs"),
                        ("Date", DateTime.Today),
                        ("IsEnabled",true)
             };

dynamic viewModel=new ExpandoObject();
var dict=(IDictionary<string,object>)viewModel;
foreach(var field in fields)
{
    dict.Add(field.name,field.value);
}
```

I'm using tuple syntaxt just to avoid typing FormField repeatedly

**UPDATE 2 -  Strongly typed class with dictionary storage**

As Stephen Muecke commented, it's harder to do binding and validation with a dynamic class. On the other hand, if the fields are known in advance, why use mapping or reflection at all?

One could create a ViewModel class that accepts some fileds, converts them to a dictionary (similar to what ExpandoObject would do) and use the dictionary as the backing store for the properties.

With a bit of C# magic like the CallMemberName attribute, the extra code is minimal. There *is* a runtime penalty for dictionary lookups, which only becomes apparent if there are a *lot* of reads/writes :

```
class MyViewModel
{
    Dictionary<string,object> _dict=new Dictionary<string,object>();

    //Get helper
    private T getter<T>([CallerMemberName]string name=null)
    {
        return _dict.TryGetValue(name,out object value)
            ? (T)Convert.ChangeType(value,typeof(T))
            : default(T);            
    }

    private void setter(object value,[CallerMemberName]string name=null)
    {
        _dict[name]=value;
    }

    public DateTime Date { 
        get => getter<DateTime>();            
        set => setter(value); 
    }               
    public string Name { 
        get => getter<string>();            
        set => setter(value); 
    }
    public bool IsEnabled { 
        get => getter<bool>();            
        set => setter(value); 
    }

    public MyViewModel(IEnumerable<FormField> fields)
    {
        _dict=fields.ToDictionary(
                         field=>field.FieldName,
                         field=>(object)field.FieldValue);
    }

}

....

var formData = new [] {
    new FormField { FieldName = "Date", FieldValue = "2017-09-14" },
    new FormField { FieldName = "Name", FieldValue = "Job blogs" },
    new FormField { FieldName = "IsEnabled", FieldValue = "true" }
};

var myViewModel = new MyViewModel(formData);
```

The setter for each property just sets a dictionary value using the property's name as the key. The getter uses `CallerMemberName` to get the property's name and use it as the key

Comment: The list of field names and values are actually retrieved via a webservice as an array so I'm not at liberty to create expando objects

Comment: @adam78 why not? You can add the names in a loop. By deriving from DynamicObject you could add a constructor that actually reads that array

Comment: @adam78 the important thing is that you don't need mapping. You only need to construct a dynamic object.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, The problem with this is the model will be used for editing data (note OP has a `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` property for a dropdownlist. `dynamic` wont work too well in that case - no 2-way model binding, no validation etc)

Comment: @StephenMuecke if the number of fields is known in advance, there's no reason to use mapping or reflection anyway. Just create a ViewModel with a constructor that accepts a `FormField[]` and sets individual values.

Comment: OP noted there were 50+ fields. That would involve an awful lot of code in a constructor using `if` or `switch` statements to match each `FieldName` with the corresponding model property :)

Comment: @StephenMuecke not that much. The fields could be stored as a dictionary and the property getters and setters delegate to it.

Comment: @Panagiotis This looks like a good solution but what if I want to go back from object to list again whilst excluding certain properies  - see my update. I would be using different viewModels with different properties to exclude so the solution would need to be reusable.

Comment: @adam78 how about you make what you want clear in the question itself? This has become a blog post. AutoMapper actually uses one of the techniques already proposed, plus reflection. Anyway, all proposed solutions work. Either you filter the fields with `Where()` and create an Expando/DynamicObject from the filtered properties, or you already have the different VM classes and pass the fields to them. Clone them if you want to store different copies of the data. Filter them in the constructors if you don't want the dictionary to contain unusable fields

Answer (score 0):

AM can map by default from `IDictionary<string, object>`(or DynamicObject) to any destination if the property names match. So you need to map from your structure to a dictionary, LINQ probably fits best, and then to your destination. The [docs](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Dynamic-and-ExpandoObject-Mapping) and the [tests](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/blob/859612d672a45c62f3cce5c8b236be796497c916/src/UnitTests/Mappers/StringDictionaryMapperTests.cs).

Comment: Similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45618005/automapper-list-to-members/45618145#45618145.

Comment: the following doesn't work: `var viewModel = Mapper.Map<Dictionary<string, string>, MyViewmodel>(formData.ToDictionary(x => x.FieldName, x => x.FieldValue))`

Comment: The type is wrong. ```IDictionary<string, object>```.

Comment: when i change the type to object I get error in my LINQ expresssion when trying to convert the list to a dictionary becuase the value is a string?

Comment: ```var viewModel = Mapper.Map<MyViewmodel>(formData.ToDictionary(x => x.FieldName, x => (object) x.FieldValue);```

Comment: The [docs](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Dynamic-and-ExpandoObject-Mapping) and the [tests](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/blob/859612d672a45c62f3cce5c8b236be796497c916/src/UnitTests/Mappers/StringDictionaryMapperTests.cs).

Comment: As the docs say, you don't need any configuration, remove that map.

Comment: Look at all those tests I linked to. Is there a CreateMap like you have? :)

Comment: I've removed create map and inialized in global.asax as ` Mapper.Initialize(cfg => { });` and it still doesnt work. MyViewModel is always empty. The only way I can get to work is by following Darins answer in the following post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7310533/dictionary-string-string-map-to-an-object-using-automapper Which kind of defeats the purpose i.e. automapper is unable to directly convert dictionary to object